# Issue when writing with WriteStream and replace-in-file in Node.js

Tags: node.js, replace, file-writing

I want to be able to write to a file during runtime while also being able to replace/delete some lines in the file.
For writing, I'm using fs.WriteStream and for replacing I'm using the [replace-in-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-in-file) library.
I'm writing many times so I can't use `fs.writeFile`

I've tried to write to a file a few lines, replace some text, then add a new line. After the replace it seems that the stream's pointer is not pointing to the end of the file anymore.

```
import * as fs from "fs";
const stream = fs.createWriteStream("./file.txt");
const replace = require("replace-in-file");
const option = {
    files: "./file.txt",
    from: /Second/,
    to: "After the first"
};

stream.write("First line \n");
stream.write("Second line \n");
stream.write("Third line \n");

replace(option)
    .then(results => {
        console.log("Replacement results:", results);
        stream.write("X");
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error("Error occurred:", error);
    });
```

**I expected the file to contain the following text:**

`First line
After the first line
Third line
X`

**Unfortunately It contains:**

`First line 
The after the first line XThird line`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not solve the problem I've experienced but I was able to have the file relatively updated during runtime. I created a `File` class which stored the data of the file in a string. Then, I wrote to the file only when important changes were made to the file.

There are a few Util functions that are not included but are fairly simple to create with `fs`.

**The class**

```js
export {};
import * as Util from "../Utility/Util";

export class File {
    /** A class to represent a file. Data isn't saved until you close/flush the file */
    private text: string; // Represents the text the file contains
    private path: string; // The path of the file
    private isOpen: boolean; // True when the file is open; False otherwise

    constructor(path: string) {
        this.path = path;
        this.text = "";
        this.isOpen = false;
    }

    open(): void {
        /**Must run before writing to file */

        if (this.isOpen) return; // Make sure file isn't opened twice
        Util.Log(`Opening file: ${this.path}`, 4);
        // Create the file if it doesn't already exist
        if (!Util.PathExists(this.path)) {
            Util.CreateFile(this.path);
        }

        this.isOpen = true;
        this.text = Util.ReadFile(this.path);
    }

    append(data: string): void {
        /** Adds data to the file */

        try {
            this.text += data;
        } catch (err) {
            const e: Error = err;
            if (e.name === "RangeError") {
                const errArr: string[] = [
                    "Error: RangeError",
                    "While writing data to files, the File class uses a string to save the data. That data is too big.",
                    "This happens every time you will try to write to much data to a file.",
                    "You must make the csv log files smaller."
                ];
                Util.SHUT_DOWN(errArr.join("\n"), e);
            }
        }
    }

    replace(oldData: string, newData: string): void {
        /** Replace the first occurrence oldData with newData */
        this.text = this.text.replace(new RegExp(oldData, ""), newData);
    }

    isEmpty(): boolean {
        /** Returns true if the file is completely empty */
        return this.text == "";
    }

    getLineWith(text: string): string {
        /** Returns the first line with the text in it */
        let lines = this.getLines();
        for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            if (lines[i].includes(text)) {
                return lines[i];
            }
        }

        return "";
    }

    deleteLineWith(data: string[]): void {
        /** Deletes the first line in the file that contains all of the strings in the array */
        let lines = this.getLines(); // Get all lines in the
        for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            let allDataFound = true;
            for (let g = 0; g < data.length; g++) {
                allDataFound = allDataFound && lines[i].includes(data[g]);
            }
            if (allDataFound) {
                const newLines = lines
                    .slice(0, i)
                    .concat(lines.slice(i + 1, lines.length));
                this.setTextByLines(newLines);
                // this.text = newLines.join("\n");
            }
        }
    }

    getLines(): string[] {
        /** Returns an array of the lines in the file */
        return this.text.split("\n");
    }

    setTextByLines(lines: string[]) {
        /** Sets the file's text given an array of lines */
        this.text = lines.join("\n");
    }

    close() {
        /** Close the file. Must run this to save changes */
        if (!this.isOpen) return; // Prevent multiple closings

        Util.Log(`Closing file: ${this.path}`, 3);
        this.flush();
        this.isOpen = false;
    }

    flush() {
        /** Writes to the file the text it supposed to have at the moment*/
        if (!this.isOpen) {
            return;
        }

        Util.WriteToFile(this.path, this.text);
    }

    getPath(): string {
        /** Get the path of the file */
        return this.path;
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```js
import {File} from './FileHandler'
let f = new File('./newFile.txt')
f.open()  // File contains 0 lines
f.append('First line\n')  // File contains 0 lines
f.append('Second line\n')  // File contains 0 lines
f.flush()   // File contains 2 lines
f.append('Third line\n')  // File contains 2 lines
f.append('Fourth line\n')  // File contains 2 lines
f.close()  // File contains 4 lines

// Note: If the file had already X lines they would not be deleted.
```